# Inner product space or Hilbert space of Quaternionic Functions

Tags: hilbert-spaces, inner-products, quaternions

In what ways can you define an inner product, $<f,g>$, to create an inner product space or Hilbert space on the set of quaternionic functions $f:\mathbb{H} \rightarrow \mathbb{H}$?

Comment: The set of *all* functions from $\Bbb H$ to $\Bbb H$? Not just continuous, or just linear functions of some kind?

Comment: I would like to know if there is a standard inner product on the set of continuous functions. Or an inner product on a smaller subspace that contains the polynomials, but that is infinite dimensional.

Comment: OK, thanks for narrowing the question :)

Comment: About Quaternionic Hilbert space you can read the article http://arxiv.org/abs/1207.0666  with further references.

Comment: @Paul Hurst. The first problem is to define the vector space. Functions $f$ must be elements of a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ ? Since $\mathbb{H}$ is not commutative, over $\mathbb{H}$ we can build right or left modules.